# Onclick and onmouseover together?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using jquery, I am interested in using **onclick** and **onmouseover** together for one volume button (found in a html5 player).

To help you visualize it, think of it as  being the YouTube volume button:

**Normally:**

[image]

**When you hover:**

[image]

**When you click (to mute):**

[image]

In my case, both events **onclick** and on **mouseover** will work, under the condition that you don't use them together.

If you add them both like the code below, then the **onclick** event won't work, the other will.

My code (simplified):

```
//When the user clicks on the volume button 

$(".volume").on("click",function() { 

$(".volume").hide();  
$(".volume_mute").show();  

});

//When the user clicks on the volume button 
$(".volume").on("mouseover", show_volume_bar);

//show_volume is a function here which shows the volume bar
//which will make the user change the volume (doesn't interest you).
```

The jQuery I am using:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

How can I make the both events (onclick and onmouseover) work together for the same button? As I said, when I use them together one of them won't work (which is onclick).

Comment: Can you create a JSFiddle or a Plunk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery [.bind()](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) to bind multiple events.

```
$( ".volume" ).bind({
  click: function() {
    $(".volume").hide();  
    $(".volume_mute").show(); 
  },
  mouseover: function() {
    show_volume_bar();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Other solution than the bind is just to use the .click() and .mouseover() functions :

```
$(".volume").click(function() {
    $(".volume").hide();
    $(".volume_mute").show();
}).mouseover(function() {
    show_volume_bar();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use CSS instead

`HTML

```
 <div class="container">
<div id="transition-hover">
    <span>Transition Hover</span>
    <div id="transition-hover-content">
        This content or image is visible only when you mouse hover     the  parent div and it has transition effect.
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#transition-hover-content {
opacity:0;   
-webkit-transition:.5s;
-moz-transition:.5s;
-o-transition:.5s;
-ms-transition:.5s;
transition:.5s;
}

#transition-hover:hover #transition-hover-content {
opacity:1;

}   
</div>
```

I used tutorial from this [a link](http://fellowtuts.com/html-css/show-content-on-mouseover-using-css/)